# Why don't we make a meta feed bot for the chatrooom?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

As the first-day meta enthusiasm has cooled down a bit now, why don't we make a meta feeds bot for our chatroom, to post the latest meta questions like on all other SE sites?

[For those who haven't seen it, here is our chatroom.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/vegetarianism)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes! Let's have one!

Meta is an important place for a developing private beta.  It's best to get as many people involved as we can, to try to hammer out the scope of this site.

Comment: In Hinduism.SE we have a bot which posts questions from main site. We have given a name "Vedavani" to it which means the "voice of vedas". Vedas are the holy scriptures of Hinduism. So, a name/term which is related to Vegetarianism/veganism to the bot would be a good idea.