# Is it time for a new questions feed into chat?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

[We have a meta feedbot now](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/why-dont-we-make-a-meta-feed-bot-for-the-chatrooom) (have had it for a good bit now) which feeds into [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52824/the-greenhouse).

Should we have a main posts feed? This would post every new question on the site into chat.

The arguments against it at the beginning were because it would post so many messages it would clog the chat, but now that the question speed has decreased (as a natural step in the cycle from private beta to public), it might be a good idea to have one.

Thoughts? Also, what should we name it if we're going to have one?

---

This has been done, it's called "The Farmer". (as Alexander suggested)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a **good idea** and that since the chat is called **The Greenhouse**, the chatbot bringing new posts to it could be called something along the lines of **The Gardener**, or **The Farmer** (the latter brings along a connotation of farm animals while the former not, so perhaps the farmer is not such a good choice).

Comment: This has been done, with the name of "The Farmer".